# How can I reduce logcat delay?

Tags: android, adb, logcat

First, there seems to be a bug in LG that makes me have to use `adb shell -x logcat` instead of adb logcat, apart from that, many times it just stops updating and keeps showing me logs from 10 minutes or 20 minutes ago until I run `adb kill-server` a couple of times and resinstall my nativescript app on my phone over and over again until it starts working again. No logs are lost though, when it starts working again I get all the previous logs too, any thoughts? I have the feeling there is some crazy buffering going on here. I'm not using Android Studio by the way, I just use tns.

Comment: I've never seen any of those, on any device.  Especially the delay thing-  that makes me think its more a problem with your setup than the device.

Comment: @GabeSechan any thought how I can verify? [Here](https://superuser.com/q/1357708/667944) is a reference to the bug in LG devices.